antiderivative of $\cos^nx \cos(nx)$
I was working on the following antiderivative problem:
$$I=\int \sin(101x) \sin^{99}x\, dx$$
After taking the tranformation $x=u+(\pi)/2$, I ended up with $$I=\int \cos(101x)\cos^{99}x\, dx$$
I tried to solve it by using the following identity:
$\cos((n+1)x)+\cos((n-1)x)=2\cos x\cos(nx)$
After applying this identity i ended up with:
$$I= 2\int \cos^{100} \cos(100x) dx -\int \cos^{99}x \cos(99x) \,dx$$
This looked relatively cleaner and more aesthetically pleasing. However I have no clue how to proceed after this. Most probably extracting a general formula for the antiderivative of $cos^nx cos(nx)$ should work, so I will be most happy if someone extended a helping hand.
BTW the original solution uses the angle sum identity for the sine, and then integration by parts. However I am more interested in my own approach. Needless to say I would  be very grateful to see other solution developments too.

Another straightforward way is to use $cos(x)=\frac{1}{2}(e^{ix}+e^{-ix})$. We get $\cos^n x \cos(nx)=\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}(e^{ix}+e^{-ix})^n(e^{inx}+e^{-inx})=\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}((e^{2ix}+1)^n+(1+e^{-2ix})^n)=\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}(\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}e^{2ix(n-k)}+\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}e^{-2ix(n-k)})=\frac{1}{2^n}\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}cos(2x(n-k))=\frac{1}{2^n}[1+\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{n}{k}cos(2x(n-k))]$
So, $\int \cos^n x \cos(nx)dx=\frac{1}{2^n}\left(x+\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{n}{k}\frac{sin(2x(n-k))}{2(n-k)}\right)+C$.
You can use the same idea to solve your original question:
$sin(101x) sin^{99}(x)=\frac{1}{(2i)^{100}}(e^{ix}-e^{-ix})^{99}(e^{101ix}-e^{-101ix})=\frac{1}{(2i)^{100}}\left((e^{2ix}-1)^{99}e^{2ix}-(1-e^{2ix})^{99}e^{-2ix}\right)=\frac{1}{(2i)^{100}}\left(\left[\frac{1}{200i}(e^{2ix}-1)^{100}\right]'-\left[\frac{1}{200i}(1-e^{-2ix})^{100}\right]'\right)=\frac{1}{(2i)^{100}}\left[\frac{1}{200i}e^{100ix}(e^{ix}-e^{-ix})^{100}-\frac{1}{200i}e^{-100ix}(e^{ix}-e^{-ix})^{100}\right]'=\left[\frac{1}{200i}\left(e^{100ix}sin^{100}(x)-e^{-100ix}sin^{100}(x)\right)\right]'=\left[\frac{1}{100}sin(100x)sin^{100}(x)\right]'$
So, $\int \sin(101x) \sin^{99}x\, dx=\frac{sin(100x)sin^{100}(x)}{100}+C$

With the binomial expansion of Euler's formula
(see e.g. eq. 18 in https://arxiv.org/abs/0809.2368 and equations 1.320.5 and 1.320.8 in the Gradshteyn-Ryzhik book)
$$
\cos^n x = \frac{1}{2^n} \sum_{s=0}^n\binom{n}{s} \cos[(2s-n)x].
$$
and using the elementary $\cos(a)\cos(b)=\frac12[\cos(a-b)+\cos(a+b)]$:
$$
\cos^n x \cos(nx)
= \frac{1}{2^n} \sum_{s=0}^n\binom{n}{s} \frac{1}{2}[\cos(2sx)+\cos(2(n-s)x)].
$$
$$
\int \cos^n x \cos(nx)dx
= \frac{1}{2^n} \sum_{s=0}^n\binom{n}{s} [\frac{1}{4} \frac{\sin(2sx)}{s}+\frac{1}{4}\frac{\sin(2(n-s)x)}{n-s}]
$$
plus taking care that for $s=n$ the last term is to be interpreted as $\sin(2(n-s)x)/[4(n-s)]\to x/2$. Further simplification is possible by noting that the terms with argument $n-s$ for $s>n/2$ replicate the terms with $s$ in the argument, so this is a sum over $s=0..\lfloor n/2\rfloor$ plus a term in the middle at $s=n/2$ if $n$ is even.

if we plug this into the original integral, then does it reproduce the correct answer?
